# What happens to second println statement? (Clojure repl)

Tags: clojure

When I call this small function in the clojure REPL it only prints the first hello world, not hello mars. Why is that? It's not lazy (as far as I understand) otherwise the exception wouldn't get hit, in addition SO tells me println causes a flush.

```
(defn foo                                                                                                                                                           
     "I don't do a whole lot."                                                                                                                                         
     [x]                                                                                                                                                               
     (println x "Hello, World!")                                                                                                                                       
     (map (fn [x] (let [_ (println "Hello, Mars")                                                                                                                      
                        __ (throw (Exception. "talking to many planets"))]                                                                                             
                    { :aliens? false }                                                                                                                                 
                   )) [1 2 3])                                                                                                                                        
)
```

Output:

> (foo nil) nil Hello, World!
>
> Exception talking to many planets  test.repl/foo/fn--6580
>   (form-init13300486174634970.clj:5)

Comment: I just tried the same code and I'm seeing the `Hello, Mars!` being printed before the `Exception` is thrown, which is what I would have predicted if you weren't seeing this weird behavior. `nil Hello, World!
(Hello, Mars
Exception talking to many planets  user/foo/fn--6 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:19)`. Clojure version is 1.5.1.

Comment: Which jvm are you using? For me: java version "1.7.0_25"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.12) (7u25-2.3.12-4ubuntu3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: I've tried it on lubuntu with `java version "1.7.0_25" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.10) (7u25-2.3.20-lubuntu0.13.04.2) OpendJDK Zero VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)` and in Windows 7 with `java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)`, I get the same result in both.

Comment: Juan, very interesting. Thanks. Will try on a few other VMs

Comment: Adding for others, Im also using clojure 1.5.1, but differently, ubuntu 13.04/64bit/openjdk, default lein template, no special jvm flags

Comment: Scratch that, I was using the bare Clojure REPL as in `java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main`, but when I tried it in the REPL-y client that leiningen uses to connect to the nREPL server it fires up, I'm seeing the same as you are.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, `map` is actually lazy, so `foo` returns a `LazySeq`, which is then forced when the REPL prints it.  Now when I run your example using bare Clojure (`java -jar clojure.jar`), I get the following output:

```
user=> (foo nil)
nil Hello, World!
(Hello, Mars
Exception talking to many planets  user/foo/fn--1 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:5)
user=>
```

I get the same result with both Clojure 1.4.0 and 1.5.1.

Now if I run via `lein repl`, I get the output you describe.  So it appears that something in the nrepl chain is affecting how things are printed.  This makes sense since nrepl is designed to communicate with clients over the network.  There appears to be a slight bug, however, in its handling of this case.  Or perhaps it re-binds *flush-on-newline* to false when printing the value?  Sorry, I haven't dived into the code deep enough to give a more definite answer.

Incidentally, if you wrap the function call in a `println`, i.e. `(println (foo nil))`, then you get the expected output shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have an idea. Map returns a lazy seq. The repl calls println (or similar) on the map which attempts to realize it, calling .toString() (or similar). Internally when print/ln is called within a print/ln it saves the output until its finishes it own, thus an exception will mean the other bits collected (print within a print) call aren't flushed.

Comment: [`println`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3407) uses [`prn`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3388) which in turns flushes the buffer whenever the [`*flush-on-newline*`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L5887) is true, which is its default value. So I don't think the thrown exception would get in the way of the buffer being flushed once `println` is called. I don't know why your are seeing that behavior though :(

Comment: Okay got it (i think), it looks like REPL-y captures the result of whole expression first in its own buffer thus when an exception occurs it prints only that rather than what was buffered for stdout. Can observe by this (map (fn [x] (Thread/sleep 5000) (println "x") x) [1 2 3]) even though println calls flush REPL-y nothing prints until after 15 seconds.